# pandas read_sql_query warns of cartesian product in query that seems to have no cartesian product

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, cross-join

I'm getting the warning

```
<mypath>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:1405: SAWarning: SELECT statement has a cartesian product between FROM element(s) "Election" and FROM element "Contest".  Apply join condition(s) between each element to resolve.
  return self.connectable.execution_options().execute(*args, **kwargs)
```

from this line in my program:

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.read_sql_query(stmt, session.bind)
```

where stmt has this value:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `VoteCount`.`Contest_Id` AS `Contest_Id`, `VoteCount`.`Selection_Id` AS `Selection_Id`, `VoteCount`.`ReportingUnit_Id` AS `ReportingUnit_Id`, _datafile.`Election_Id` AS `Election_Id`, `VoteCount`.`_datafile_Id` AS `_datafile_Id`, `VoteCount`.`CountItemType` AS `CountItemType`, `VoteCount`.`Count` AS `Count` 
FROM `VoteCount` 
    INNER JOIN _datafile ON _datafile.`Id` = `VoteCount`.`_datafile_Id` 
    INNER JOIN `Contest` ON `Contest`.`Id` = `VoteCount`.`Contest_Id` 
    INNER JOIN `ComposingReportingUnitJoin` ON `ComposingReportingUnitJoin`.`ChildReportingUnit_Id` = `VoteCount`.`ReportingUnit_Id` 
    INNER JOIN `CandidateSelection` ON `CandidateSelection`.`Id` = `VoteCount`.`Selection_Id`
    INNER JOIN `Candidate` ON `Candidate`.`Id` = `CandidateSelection`.`Candidate_Id` 
    INNER JOIN `Party` ON `Party`.`Id` = `CandidateSelection`.`Party_Id` 
    INNER JOIN `CandidateContest` ON `CandidateContest`.`Id` = `Contest`.`Id` 
    INNER JOIN `Office` ON `Office`.`Id` = `CandidateContest`.`Office_Id` 
    INNER JOIN `ReportingUnit` AS `ReportingUnit_1` ON `ReportingUnit_1`.`Id` = `Office`.`ElectionDistrict_Id` 
    INNER JOIN `ReportingUnit` AS `ReportingUnit_2` ON `ReportingUnit_2`.`Id` = `VoteCount`.`ReportingUnit_Id` 
    INNER JOIN `Election` ON `Election`.`Id` = _datafile.`Election_Id` 
WHERE _datafile.`Election_Id` = %(Election_Id_1)s AND `ComposingReportingUnitJoin`.`ParentReportingUnit_Id` = %(ParentReportingUnit_Id_1)s
```

It seems to me that there is already a join condition between each table. Schematically (where "|" indicates a join between the table to the right and the table above):

```
VoteCount
    |_datafile
        |Election
    |Contest
        |CandidateContest
            |Office
                |ReportingUnit_1
    |ComposingReportingUnitJoin
    |CandidateSelection
        |Candidate
        |Party
    |ReportingUnit_2
```

What am I missing? Why am I getting the warning, and what might I do to resolve it?

Comment: Any reason why all table names are quoted with backticks *except* `_datafile`?

Comment: I copied & pasted the value from my IDE (PyCharm). I'd guess the reason is that _datafile is the only table name without any capital letters.